# How do I update my SQL database using XML?

Tags: sql, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patients>
  <Patient EMail="LeBron@James.com">
    <FirstName>LeBron</FirstName>
    <LastName>James</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient EMail="Kobe@Bryant.com">
    <FirstName>Kobe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bryant</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient EMail="Allen@Iverson.com">
    <FirstName>Allen</FirstName>
    <LastName>Iverson</LastName>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```

I want to store it in a SQL database which I have done successfully/

I then added some more data to the same XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patients>
  <Patient EMail="LeBron@James.com">
    <FirstName>LeBron</FirstName>
    <LastName>James</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient EMail="Kobe@Bryant.com">
    <FirstName>Kobe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bryant</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient EMail="Allen@Iverson.com">
    <FirstName>Allen</FirstName>
    <LastName>Iverson</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <!-- New data starts here -->
  <Patient EMail="trtr@Iverson.com">
    <FirstName>tr</FirstName>
    <LastName>rson</LastName>
  </Patient>
  <Patient EMail="wewn@Iverson.com">
    <FirstName>Awerwren</FirstName>
    <LastName>Iveww</LastName>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```

But it does not update in SQL database at runtime.....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1 There is neither XML nor a question here.

Comment: You are going to have to clear this question up or it will get closed.  What is your DB access library and platform? What does your update code look like?

Comment: we can't suggest u, we can't suggest u, because nobody will have an idea of what you're talking about

Comment: @Jay there was an xml. @Kumar just didn't read about markup, how to format questions/answers.

Comment: Rephrase your question dude or this will get closed real soon....

Comment: As @steve says, you need to tell us more about what database API you're using? Are you using MS SQL Server, if so what version? What version of C#/.NET?

Comment: @Kumar: it would be helpful to know what database platform you're using and how you're accessing it. Please edit your question and add the appropriate tags. It would also be helpful to know what the table looks like (columns, constraints, etc).  Without that information there's not much anyone can do to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted, I'm guessing that perhaps there's a primary or unique key on the Patient table's FirstName and LastName columns, and the second time you try to insert data into the database this constraint is causing the inserts to fail.

Just a guess.  Post more information and perhaps we can narrow it down a bit for you.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yes Primary Key is there in Table...Solution?

Comment: I am thinking the same thing. If we are wrong, post more details about any SQL errors you receive or stack trace of an exception that pops up.

Comment: @Kumar: if there is a primary key on the FirstName and LastName columns you won't be able to insert the same names multiple times.  The solution is either to remove the data before trying to re-insert it, or to change your code to do an UPSERT or MERGE (depending on your database) instead of an INSERT.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previous database. Create a new database with the new XML.